# Prime NG Menu - Focus on first element when activated

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am attempting to move the focus from the prime ng menu to the first of the list elements that appear when you toggle the menu. Here is what I have so far.

In the template I have:

```
<p-menu appendTo="body" #menu [popup]="true" [model]="menuItems" (onShow)="openMenu()"></p-menu>
```

And in my typescript I have:

```
@ViewChild('menu', { read: ElementRef }) menu: ElementRef;

...

openMenu() {
    const menuItem = (
      this.menu.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(
        'p-menuitem'
      ) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>
    )[0];

    menuItem.focus();
  }
```

When testing this, the element is definitely being discovered, and I can set attributes on the element. However, setting the focus does not appear to be working. Are there any decent ways of accessing DOM elements and setting focus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me in the end:

```
openMenu() {
    const menuItem = (
      this.menu.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(
        'p-menuitem-link'
      ) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>
    )[0];

    setTimeout(() => {
      menuItem.focus();
    }, 1);
  }
```